# Upgrading Chromium OS to Chrome OS mount error

Tags: bash, chromium, google-chrome-os

I'm trying to upgrade Chromium OS to Chrome OS with http://goo.gl/4suhf. Unfortunately, when running this script (inside Chromium OS), it says:

```
wget stuff
unpacking zipfile
RootFS Start: 286720 RootFS Size: 2359520
mount: special device /dev/sda12 does not exist
```

After that the script ends. I don't have a /dev/sda12, I just dd'd the Vanilla build to my hard drive. If you're interested in solving this, please review the code at goo.gl/4suhf. I did that myself but I'm not that good in analysing code! I've made up that the RootFS things are at the end of the file. Following this guide: http://zzsethzz.blogspot.be/2013/02/install-chromium-upgrade-it-to-chrome.html

Answer (score 1):

i'm guessing by vanilla build you mean one of Hexxeh's builds. Try using one of the updated builds by Arnoldthebat.co.uk < The newer builds create the dev/sda12 ur missing.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If your using a USB stick or depending on your drive setup, you may need to rename the two lines at the end of the script from sdA to sdb. In the newest script there should be a /dev/sdb12 and on the dd= line an /sdb3